# How to teach my dog an once-taught, but now forgotten trick?

Tags: dogs, training, psychology

My dog ​​knew how to give the leg and sit when the order was given, but I had gone to live elsewhere and she was left without anyone to play with her for some years because I was the only one who did it, so I know they forgot those tricks. I want to teach them again, but I don't know if I can because she is old.

Comment: I think you might be surprised. There might be some confusion to begin with, but I think your dog might still remember with a little guidance.

Comment: Thanks, i will try

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your dog can relearn a trick. Most likely, they never truly forgot it.

It will take practice and patience, but if you can devote at least 15 minutes of training session each day, your dog will slowly remember. Also, try to see if your dog can perform the trick without the incentives of a treat during a random part of the day. Be supportive and kind to your dog, and they should remember the trick by a few weeks.

For example, for the trick "sit", you would hold the treat above your dog's head and command them to sit, gently nudging them into a sitting position if they didn't sit right away, and properly rewarding them. If you found training with clickers worked before, use that again.

Even if your dog had truly forgotten the trick, [old dogs *can* learn new tricks](https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/can-old-dogs-learn-new-tricks#:%7E:text=Old%20dogs%20can%20learn%20new%20tricks.&text=In%20fact%2C%20adult%20dogs%20are,learn%20new%20routines%20more%20easily.), so you can certainly reteach the trick to him.

Sources:

- [mypet.com - Tips on Training Dogs](https://www.mypet.com/new-pet-owner/tips-training-dog.aspx)
- [thesprucepets.com - How to Teach a Puppy to Sit](https://www.thesprucepets.com/how-to-teach-a-puppy-to-sit-2805071)